# If I was to record a live, streaming video, what negative effects would there be?

Tags: audio, video, recording, screen-recorder

If I wanted to record, say, a webinar, or a Twitch video, using some form of screen-capture/screen-recording software, what (if any) negative effects would I need to accommodate for? I.e. Drop in visual quality, sound etc.

I do want to record this as good quality as I can, so any downsides (however minor) are welcome to be explained.

Comment: You're better off trying to cap the stream itself vs displaying the stream then re-encoding the frames from you're screen. Any recompression like that will always be lossy.

Comment: @Linef4ult care to elaborate please? My knowledge of this is limited.

Comment: I think he was referring to using a capture card (more CPU intensive however) instead of software screen capture, however I think the application depends on what exactly you want to do. Do you want to also stream games on twitch? Are you only going to use twitch? Different streaming platforms support different streaming qualities and settings. You have to accommodate for those as well.

Comment: @Spokey no, all I want to do is record the webcasts, I will not be making any of my own.